# How to write a select query for displaying data on a table in another way using Postgresql?

Tags: postgresql, join, plpgsql, dynamic-sql, crosstab

I want to write a select query to pick data from a table which is shown in this image below,PICTURE_1
[1.Table Containing Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSJ5t.jpg)
and display it like this image in this link below, PICTURE_2
[2.Result of the query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CgwwQ.jpg)

About the data: The first picture shows data logged into a table for 2 seconds from 3 IDs(1,2&3) having 2 sub IDs (aa&bb). Values and timestamp are also displayed in the picture. The table conatins only 3 column as shown in PICTURE_1. Could you guys help me write a query to display data in the table to get displayed as shown in the second image using Postgresql?. You can extract ID name using substring function. The language that Im using is plpgsql. Any ideas/logic also will be good.Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this. Here row value has been shown in column wise and also use CTE.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
WITH cte_t AS (
     SELECT LEFT(name, 1) id
          , RIGHT(name, POSITION('.' IN REVERSE(name)) - 1) t_name
          , value
          , time_stamp
     FROM test
)
SELECT id
     , time_stamp :: DATE "date"
     , time_stamp :: TIME "time"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t_name = 'aa' THEN value END) "aa"
     , MAX(CASE WHEN t_name = 'bb' THEN value END) "bb"
FROM cte_t
GROUP BY id, time_stamp
ORDER BY date, time, id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=6d35047560b3f83e6c906584b23034e9

Comment: This idea is really useful especially in cases where we have numerous records in the table.

Comment: Thanks @JoyalJoy for your response. If it really help You then mark this answer accepted and useful so that anyone can pick this answer without any doubt.

Comment: Yes already did it, it will be there when my reputation becomes >15. Sir, can you suggest any method to try out if I wanted to take the average of 'value' in between a specific time?

Comment: You can try SELECT AVG(val) FROM t WHERE time BETWEEN '2021-08-01' AND '2021-08-20'

Comment: How can I use this in a case statement? Because I have to take average values of 6 tags, so multiple select queries will be there, right?

Comment: will average value show with all row or datetime wise? AVG(aa) and avg(bb) right. Please provide a sample

Comment: you can check from this url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=22b26101305637567bb6ca07ce6d7b35

Comment: Sir, then I'll post it as another question. Please visit this link. https://stackoverflow.com/q/68888474/16501271

Comment: Sir, Could you please explain what is happening here when we use MAX() function?

Comment: As row value will show column wise then use MAX() and If MAX() isn't used here so name column must be placed in GROUP BY clause and NULL value will show  either in name = 'aa' or name = 'bb' because in name column either aa or bb exists not both and also row number increases. It's one kind of PIVOT type query.

Answer (score 1):

Check this query [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=33709eedf5491972558ed42576f549be)

```sql
with cte (name, value, timeStamp) as (values 
    ('1.aa', 1, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('2.aa', 2, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('3.aa', 3, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('1.bb', 4, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('2.bb', 5, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('3.bb', 6, '2021-08-20 10:10:01'),
    ('1.aa', 7, '2021-08-20 10:10:02'),
    ('2.aa', 8, '2021-08-20 10:10:02'),
    ('3.aa', 9, '2021-08-20 10:10:02'),
    ('1.bb', 0, '2021-08-20 10:10:02'),
    ('2.bb', 1, '2021-08-20 10:10:02'),
    ('3.bb', 2, '2021-08-20 10:10:02')
), sub_cte as (
    select split_name[1] as id, split_name[2] as name, value, tt::date as date, tt::time as time from (
        select 
            regexp_split_to_array(name, '\.') split_name, 
            value, 
            to_timestamp(timestamp, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as tt 
        from cte
    ) foo
)
select id, date, time, a.value as aa, b.value as bb from sub_cte a
left join (
    select * from sub_cte where name = 'bb'
) as b using (id, date, time)
where a.name = 'aa'
```

Result

```
 id |    date    |   time   | aa | bb 
----+------------+----------+----+----
 1  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:01 |  1 |  4
 2  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:01 |  2 |  5
 3  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:01 |  3 |  6
 1  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:02 |  7 |  0
 2  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:02 |  8 |  1
 3  | 2021-08-20 | 10:10:02 |  9 |  2
(6 rows)
```