# Query for selecting multiple data along with average values in between a specific time using Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, case, average, dynamic-sql

I have data inside a table from two different dates for the same source of data. Sample of data is given below

[image: Sample table].

This table contains logged data for 2 seconds from a server having 1&2 as branches and aa,bb&cc as their sub-branches. In the original table, data is getting logged in a similar way for each second. I want to take the average value of each subgroup in between a specified time so that I can display my data as shown below. Can you guys help me with writing a select query?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert avg_aa either bigint or double precision. First substract id and name from name field then calculate average by id and date.

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
    WITH cte_t AS (
     SELECT LEFT(name, 1) id
          , RIGHT(name, POSITION('.' IN REVERSE(name)) - 1) t_name
          , value
          , time_stamp
     FROM test
)
SELECT id
          , time_stamp :: DATE "date"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'aa' THEN value END) :: BIGINT "avg(aa)"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'bb' THEN value END) :: BIGINT "avg(bb)"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'cc' THEN value END) :: BIGINT "avg(cc)"
     FROM cte_t
     GROUP BY id, time_stamp :: DATE
     ORDER BY "date", id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=8113ce4fd19d2865dcc5757d0e920759

Use double precision in avg column

```
-- PostgreSQL(v11)
WITH cte_t AS (
     SELECT LEFT(name, 1) id
          , RIGHT(name, POSITION('.' IN REVERSE(name)) - 1) t_name
          , value
          , time_stamp
     FROM test
)
SELECT id
          , time_stamp :: DATE "date"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'aa' THEN value END) :: DOUBLE PRECISION "avg(aa)"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'bb' THEN value END) :: DOUBLE PRECISION "avg(bb)"
          , AVG(CASE WHEN t_name = 'cc' THEN value END) :: DOUBLE PRECISION "avg(cc)"
     FROM cte_t
     GROUP BY id, time_stamp :: DATE
     ORDER BY "date", id;
```

Please check from url https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=c70fe828008b13f7eb3feefc080f8038

Comment: hi @JoyalJoy please check this.

Comment: Please check above query and let me know if any question regard this or is it helpful to you.

Comment: I'm still working on this query. I have a lot of data in my table. So when I query only for average value between a specific time for 'aa' it is picking up all the data in column 'ID' and 'date' thereby duplicating values for each value in 'ID' and date. Where clause might help, right?

Comment: @JoyalJoy any update about this query. Is it helpful to you?

Comment: Definitely, I'll post the update once testing is done after debugging my logging script.

Comment: RahulBiswas, the query is really helpful. Thank you for sharing your expertise with us. For people who might use this logic in the future and are new to this field, please make sure that you guys are taking average values from a field of datatype mentioned in this link https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-numeric.html.

Comment: Welcome @JoyalJoy for your feedback. AVG() function returns float point value but you question expected no digit after decimal. That's why I converted it.